# Is there a way to "flatten" a picker view in Swift?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Is there a way to remove the barrel effect from a UIPickerView in Swift?  I'd like to to simply scroll up and down, without the simulated 3D cylinder that's built in.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. Pretty sure you might as well just build a `UITableView` at this point.